# SendGrid Link Branding gives ssl issue

Tags: email, sendgrid

Unfortunately, nobody is responding to my support ticket so I think it's a problem needs someone with experience with sendgrid

the reproduction is simple:

1. did the Domain Authentication and Link Branding
2. Added all the necessary record to my DNS configs
3. All verified in SendGrid dashboard.
4. Tried sending an email and click on the link it gives me this

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm having similar issues with link branding and Sendgrid support.

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue might be that you that you use `https` links, but you don't have a "TLS pass-trough" set-up for them. It's really poorly explained on Sendgrid's branded links help page, but you can see a mention of it [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/custom-ssl-configurations/). Basically you need something that will resolve TLS on your side and forward the request to sendgrid. It can be a proxy, as suggested on that help page, or i.e. a cloudfront distribution with a custom origin pointing to sendgrid and a certificate covering your branded link domain covered.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Cloudflare, I had luck following this [guide](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/content-delivery-networks#using-cloudflare) in their documentation in order to get it to work. Sendgrid also recommends Fastly and KeyCDN.

The only drawback is you also have to contact customer support in order to request that SSL click and open tracking be enabled on your account.

Comment: Works great. The customer support was very responsive though and it was all set up within 48h.

Answer (score -2):

Give API Key its full access, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. API Keys
3. Edit API Key
4. Full Access
5. Update

---

Whitelist your domain, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. Sender Authentication
3. Domain Authentication
4. Select DNS Host
5. Enter your domain name
6. Copy all records and put them in your Advanced DNS management console

---

Add a branded link, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. Sender Authentication
3. Link Branding
4. Follow the steps on the screen
5. Copy all records and put them in your Advanced DNS management console

NOTE: When adding records, make sure not to have domain name in the host. Crop it out.

---

Now, I attach any http or https url in `html_content` like

```
html_content="<a href='https://www.python.org/'>Python</a>")
```

When I receive email, and click on the link, it loads perfectly.

This is the link generated - [Python](http://url6358.kartikeybhardwaj.com/ls/click?upn=xJzLNo-2BOCA9v6-2BOTXF8xmrv7nWtkUf3fn5LmFwUDgf64f4Qw5lLUgX4xZ-2BIjNaqZaq3n_eEj2pUTj6bHa8RJCDdR07sgamWRUBKswK4KVzjuACzY41Q1AtlioefsRbssAEroEAcJB9ECdQIrChT7rJroOjzcWtMYheABOp1dhEMwPZDVUesIzv-2B1s-2BshsCySsLsmPoj8v0q4t-2Fvv5-2FQJh0Rm6cVvIK76qgWO54yH9g62JMVzGoyWL6daezz1pb50NM2JHcLyxj1dcGRwMwIAez8cPIEMx07MP2-2B9JdzoHaFB62gU-3D)

Comment: This is the process in the documentation and the process I followed before. I just ran through it again just to be sure and I'm still having certificate problems. So thanks but it seems that the solution is to use something other than SendGrid. Shame, they used to be cool but now they don't even answer support requests.